# How to get the error message in Controller or Route after handling exception in errorHandler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I had to customized **Sftp Inbound** default handler `LoggingHandler` and using my own `CustomizedErrorHandler` which extends `ErrorHandler`. But I can't return any message to my controller after handling exceptions.

I was researching couple of days and I found nothing to show my customized message to my UI using `Controller`. Below are some code snippet from my `CustomizedErrorHandler`, `SftpInboundConfiguration`.

**`SftpInboundConfiguration`**

```
public IntegrationFlow fileFlow() {
    SftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec spec = Sftp
            .inboundAdapter(getSftpSessionFactory())
            .preserveTimestamp(true)
            .remoteDirectory(getSourceLocation())
            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
            .deleteRemoteFiles(false)
            .localDirectory(new File(getDestinationLocation()));

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(spec, e -> e.id(BEAN_ID)
                    .autoStartup(false)
                    .poller(sftpPoller())
            )
            .channel(sftpReceiverChannel())
            .handle(sftpInboundMessageHandler())
            .get();
}
```

... ... ...

```
public PollerMetadata sftpPoller() {
        PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
        List<Advice> adviceChain = new ArrayList<>();
        pollerMetadata.setErrorHandler(customErrorMessageHandler());
        pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(5000));
        return pollerMetadata;
}
```

... ... ...

```
private CustomErrorMessageHandler customErrorMessageHandler() {
        return new CustomErrorMessageHandler(
                controlChannel(),
                BEAN_ID
        );
}
```

**`CustomErrorMessageHandler`**

```
public class CustomErrorMessageHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    private final MessageChannel CONTROL_CHANNEL;
    private final String BEAN_ID;

    public CustomErrorMessageHandler(
                  MessageChannel controlChannel, 
                  String beanID
    ) {
        this.CONTROL_CHANNEL = controlChannel;
        this.BEAN_ID = beanID;
    }

    public void handleError(@NotNull Throwable throwable) {
        final Throwable rootCause = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(throwable);
        if (rootCause instanceof MessagingException) {
            log.error("MessagingException : {} ", rootCause.getMessage());
        } else if (rootCause instanceof SftpException) {
            log.error("SftpException : {}", rootCause.getMessage());
        }   ... ... ... 
        else {
            log.error("Unknown : Cause : {} , Error : {}", 
                                 rootCause, rootCause.getMessage());
        }


        log.info("Stopping SFTP Inbound");
        boolean is_stopped = CONTROL_CHANNEL.send(
                 new GenericMessage<>("@" + BEAN_ID + ".stop()"));
        if (is_stopped) {
            log.info("SFTP Inbound Stopped.");
        } else {
            log.info("SFTP Inbound Stop Failed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to save some customized message from `if-else` statements and need to show it in UI. Is there any way to save the message and show it using Route or `Controller` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't customize the error handler, use `poller.errorChannel("myErrorChannel")` instead.

Then add an error channel flow

```java
@Bean
IntegrationFlow errors() {
    return IntegrationFLows.from("myErrorChannel")
        .handle(...)
        ...
        .get();
```

The message sent to the handler is an `ErrorMessage` with a `MessagingException` payload, with `cause` and `failedMessage` which was the message at the point of the failure and `originalMessage` which is the original message emitted by the adapter.

After handling the exception, you can simply call a method on your controller to tell it the state.

Comment: I couldn't understand `poller.errorChannel(...)` . Can you please give an example ? I am getting only `poller.setErrorHandler(...)` in my **`PollerMetadata`**

Comment: instead of `.poller(sftpPoller())` use `.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000).errorChannel("myErrors")`).

Comment: The `PollerSpec` has `advice(Advice... advices)`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/dsl/PollerSpec.html

Comment: sorry for asking the previous question. It was my typing mistake that I was making in my code. Thank you so much for your answer and comments. I will comment again If I stuck to any other issues.

Comment: You can use `.handle(controller, "setState")` to send a message containing state to your controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and suggestion. Specially the last comment is very interesting. :D